# Xamarin form - how to increase width of tabs in tabbed page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using `tabbed page` which contains 3 pages on top. I want to increase width of tabs here is my code:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.TabbedMainPage" Title="Tasks"
            xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:App1" >


    <local1:ToDo  >

    </local1:ToDo>

    <local1:Doing>

    </local1:Doing>

    <local1:Done>

    </local1:Done>


</TabbedPage>
```

Please check the image below how tabbed page looks like now
[image]

i have added blue arrow in image, so 1st tab i want to width until where arrow finish

Comment: You have to do this in either a custom renderer or in the Android styles

Comment: any code for that?